# SQL QUERY - Omit ALL duplicate results

Tags: sql

I need to return values in a column where only the unique values are returned. I know that DISTINCT will return only unique values, however i need to completely omit any that are duplicated.

i.e.

```
Column 1    Column 2
----------------------
123456789   27/02/2014
123456789   25/02/2014
654789897   27/02/2014
```

To return only "654789897 27/02/2014" and omit the other results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select column1, column2
from table t
group by column1, column2
having count(*) = 1;
```

EDIT: (based on comment by knkarthick24)

Depending on what the OP intends, this might also be correct:

```
select column1, max(column2)
from table t
group by column1
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Does not the below query is correct according to the question?

select column1, max(column2) as column2
from table t
group by column1
having count(*) = 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1,column2 
from tbl 
where column1 in(
select column1
from table
group by column1 having count(column1)=1)
```

Its good to have Having and GroupBy

Let me know if that works:)